# Word for someone that owns a media house

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for someone that owns a media house? Can I call him a *proprietor*?

Comment: What do you mean by *media house*? This phase has no meaning to me.

Answer (score 3):

In the great days of newspapers, owners of the like of Northcliffe, Beaverbrook and Rothermere were called press *barons*.

Comment: And the owners of large breweries were called *the beerage*.

Answer (score 2):

I think a term that is sometimes used is "media mogul." At least that's how people describe Rupert Murdoch in the U.S.

Answer (score 1):

*Proprietor* is definitely used for someone who owns a newspaper or magazine. I don't think it would be used for the owner of a TV station, though.